# To be or not to be - Optional arguments inside definition of macro

Tags: fancyhdr, xparse

The version A part in the following example is to define `header/footer` by macros from package `fancyhdr`.

Though this version is workable, it's a awkward achievement because the same part of code(`\ifnum...`) is written twice.

Except the optional argument #2, all other code is exactly the same. To improve it, I tried the version B below, but it does not work at all.

**It will be awfull especially when the same part of code is large.**

So, to sumarize, is there a better way of handling optional arguments (to be there or not) to avoid heavy duplicate code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry,fancyhdr,xparse}
\geometry{showframe}

\begin{document}
first page\par\vspace{80em} second page
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

%Version A: workable %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\NewDocumentCommand{\firstpage}{momm}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}
  {#1{%
      \ifnum\value{page}=1
      #3% content of header/footer only at the first page
      \else
      #4% content of header/footer at the rest pages
      \fi
    }
  }
  {#1[#2]% the only diferrence between the two branches of \IfNoValueTF is, whether introducing the optional argument #2
    {%
      \ifnum\value{page}=1
      #3% content of header/footer only at the first page
      \else
      #4% content of header/footer at the rest pages
      \fi
    }
  }
}%\firstpage

% Test
\firstpage{\fancyhead}[c]{only at the first page}{at rest pages}
\firstpage{\rhead}{r first}{r rest}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% Version B: not workable %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\NewDocumentCommand{\firstpageA}{momm}{%
   #1 \IfNoValueTF{#2}{}{[#2]}
      \ifnum\value{page}=1
      #3% content of header/footer only at the first page
      \else
      #4% content of header/footer at the rest pages
      \fi
}%\firstpageA

% Test
\firstpageA{\fancyhead}[c]{only at the first page}{at rest pages}
\firstpageA{\rhead}{r first}{r rest}  

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would suggest to use `O{}` instead of `o` and then just unconditionally put `#1[#2]` with empty `#2` in case of no optional arg.

Comment: You don't need such a complicated setup for the page style of the first page. Simply put \thispagestyle{firstpage} at the begin

Comment: But to avoid large code repetition put the code in a auxiliary command and then use this in tje switches.

Comment: @ Sergei As the document of fancyhdr does not mention it I don't know macros like \chead, \rfoot can have a optioanal argument. In this example, an optioanal arg with a value of empty does work. By this example, what I want is to find a universal approch to handle those macro that does not permit empty optional argument.

Comment: @Ulrike Yes, an auxiliry command is a good idea. But for some reason(expand sequence, detokenize, tokenize...etc), I wonder if there are much better methods. And I think this is a category question which is  of universal significance.

Comment: your example seems strange, neither version produces a page head as far as i can see? What output do you get/expect from the "workable" version?

Comment: Thank you David for your pointing out a flaw in my code. What you meet is for the reason that there is nothing in main body. Header/footer alone will not give any typeset.I'll correct it. And as my comments in code says, version B does not work, but version A does. These codes get a different header between the first page and the rest pages.

Comment: Why do you want to use both syntaxes? Just use the `\fancyhead` syntax and forget about `\lhead`, `\chead` and `\rhead`.

Comment: @egreg The root reason I pose this question is: whether there are better ways that has the similar form in version B  handling those macro that does not permit empty optional argument to prevent heavy duplicate cods. Maybe I give a bad example because macros like \rhead, \chead from fancyhdr permit empty optional argument. But for other macros that does not permit empty optional augument, this is a question.

Comment: I could show in general how to avoid duplication but the example makes it so confusing, I get no page headers at all and you start the first page before specifying the page head, `\fancyhead` and friends should almost always be in the document preamble. You are asking how to optimise code while making it work the same way, so you should post a working document, then answers can check they get the same result, but with simpler coding.

Comment: @David I have updated my code(add text in main body). Please comment the version B part, and you'll see the typeset by version A with chead and rhead. I just compile these updated code and succeed get two pages with header. I'll attach my figure of result

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe it's not useful to try and fit an awkward syntax into a command like that.

It's more rewarding to spend a bit more time in devising a friendlier syntax. Here I propose

```
\sethf{
  head = <contents of all headers, except possibly the first>,
  foot = <contents of all footers, except possibly the first>,
  pos = <l|c|r>,
  first = <possible exception for first header/footer>,
}
```

Only one among `head` or `foot` should be used in a call of `\sethf`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,xparse}

\usepackage[paper=a6paper]{geometry} % smaller pictures
\usepackage{lipsum} % mock text

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\sethf}{m}
 {
  \tl_clear:N \l__lyl_hf_pos_tl
  \tl_clear:N \l__lyl_hf_first_tl
  \tl_clear:N \l__lyl_hf_headfoot_tl
  \keys_set:nn { lyl/hf } { #1 }
  \lyl_hf_set:
 }

\keys_define:nn { lyl/hf }
 {
  head  .code:n   = \__lyl_hf_aux:Nn \fancyhead { #1 },
  foot  .code:n   = \__lyl_hf_aux:Nn \fancyfoot { #1 },
  pos   .tl_set:N = \l__lyl_hf_pos_tl,
  first .tl_set:N = \l__lyl_hf_first_tl,
 }

\tl_new:N \l__lyl_hf_headfoot_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__lyl_hf_aux:Nn
 {
  \cs_set_eq:NN \__lyl_hf_temp:w #1
  \tl_set:Nn \l__lyl_hf_headfoot_tl { #2 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \lyl_hf_set:
 {
  \tl_if_empty:NT \l__lyl_hf_first_tl
   {
    \tl_set_eq:NN \l__lyl_hf_first_tl \l__lyl_hf_headfoot_tl
   }
  \__lyl_hf_set:NVVV 
   \__lyl_hf_temp:w        % \fancyhead or \fancyfoot
   \l__lyl_hf_pos_tl       % position
   \l__lyl_hf_first_tl     % first page
   \l__lyl_hf_headfoot_tl  % other pages
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__lyl_hf_set:Nnnn
 {
  #1 [ #2 ] { \int_compare:nTF { \value{page} = 1 } { #3 } { #4 } }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__lyl_hf_set:Nnnn { NVVV }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\sethf{
  head = other pages,
  first = first page,
  pos = c,
}

\sethf{pos = r, foot=\thepage}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

To answer your question: use a macro for the duplicate code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,xparse}

\usepackage[paper=a6paper]{geometry} % smaller pictures
\usepackage{lipsum} % mock text

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\NewDocumentCommand{\firstpage}{momm}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}
   {\setfirstpage{#1}{#3}{#4}}
   {\setfirstpage{#1[#2]}{#3}{#4}}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\setfirstpage}{mmm}
 {
  #1{\ifnum\value{page}=1 #2\else #3\fi}
 }

\firstpage{\fancyhead}[c]{first page}{other pages}
% can also be \firstpage{\chead}{first page}{other pages}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-2]

\end{document}
```

You *might* replace the definition here with

```
\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\firstpage}{momm}
 {
  \exp_last_unbraced:Nf #1 \IfNoValueTF{#2}{}{[#2]}
   {
    \int_compare:nTF { \value{page}=1 } { #3 } { #4 } 
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff
```

but it's not something I'd do myself. The code `\IfNoValueTF{#2}{}{[#2]}` can be more simply replaced with `\IfValueT{#2}{[#2]}`.

Comment: Thank you @egreg for you help! I'm learning it. Would you tell me why the version B in my example is a failure experiment?

Comment: @lyl `\fancyhead` wants to see `[` after it, not `\IfNoValueTF`.

Comment: Following your suggest,I tried `\expandafter#1 \IfNoValueTF{#2}{}{[#2]}`, still failed. what's wrong with this?

Comment: @lyl You'd need 10 expansion steps, which means 1023 `\expandafter` tokens.

Comment: I'm shocked. Just a short command `\IfNoValueTF{#2}{}{[#2]}` needs 1023 \expandafter tokens. Does that mean it is impposible to achieve my goal(to determine if a optional argument as whole to be or not to be) by terms of my version B? Or is there any other way to modify the achievement of version B?

Comment: @lyl `\exp_last_unbraced:Nf #1 \IfNoValueTF{#2}{}{[#2]}` (needs to be inside `\ExplSyntaxOn` and `\ExplSyntaxOff`)

Comment: I tried with the idea above(  `#1
  \ExplSyntaxOn
  \exp_last_unbraced:Nf #1 \IfNoValueTF{#2}{}{[#2]}
  \ExplSyntaxOff
      \ifnum\value{page}=1...`), but still fail. Why? Is it convinient for you to give a whole MWE?

Comment: @lyl That's not how you should use `\ExplSyntaxOn` and `\ExplSyntaxOff`. They should surround the definition.

Comment: I tried as your suggest to surround the difinition, but still fail. Would you please provide a MWE of this? Thank you.

Comment: @lyl Why would you do it the hard way when there are much easier ones?

Comment: If your idea `\exp_last_unbraced:Nf #1 \IfNoValueTF{#2}{}{[#2]}` does work, I don't think this is a hard way. I'll regard it as a perfect solution.

Comment: @lyl I added it and no, it's ***not*** a perfect solution.

Comment: With the code `\int_compare:nTF { \value{page}=1 } { #3 } { #4 }` replacing original part of  `\ifnum\value...`, it works. And this new version I think is also simple and clear though I don't understand why `\ifnum...` can not be used here. And also thank you for your hint about `\IfValueT{#2}{[#2]}`.

Comment: @lyl Mixing programming styles is not something I'd recommend.

Comment: This new solution can be promoted in many other similar cases. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

For the specific example, simply using `\thispagestyle` on the first page would probably be better, but for the general question, you can avoid pre-scanning the arguments until after the tests for optional argument, and a helper macro can avoid code duplication:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry,fancyhdr,xparse}
\geometry{showframe}

\begin{document}
first page\par\vspace{80em} second page
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}


\def\fpageTF#1#2#3{#1{\ifnum\value{page}=1 #2\else #3\fi}}



\NewDocumentCommand{\firstpage}{mo}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#2}{\fpageTF{#1}}{\fpageTF{#1[#2]}}}


% Test
\firstpage{\fancyhead}[c]{only at the first page}{at rest pages}
\firstpage{\rhead}{r first}{r rest}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\end{document}
```

Comment: oh I just noticed this is similar to  egreg's second version (I'd only noticed the first version with the key syntax:-), I may delete, although it's slightly different as I delay the final two `mm` arguments....

Comment: Though this is similar to egreg's second version, I learned new tricks from you. Thank you! Please don't delete your answer.